# Is there any API to fetch both rear and front camera view at the same time?

Tags: android

I have a requirement to show both rear and front camera in a single display. Is it possible to show both simultaneously. Is there any api to fetch both views at the same time?

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stack Overflow! By the way, I noticed you haven't accepted any answers to any of your questions. If you could do that, it would be super swell! Just click the check mark under the voting arrows on the answer you like best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as a single camera... Just double.

Two SurfaceHolders, and two Camera instances.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

Comment: *Sounds* plausible, but if you actually try it, the second open(int) will throw an exception.