# Is there any android phone allowing to use both the rear and front camera at the same time?

Tags: android, camera

I am doing a project on android phone and I hope to use the two camera at the same time. According to [Is there any API to fetch both rear and front camera view at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8410876/is-there-any-api-to-fetch-both-rear-and-front-camera-view-at-the-same-time)     , it may be possible to realize it. However, when I tried it on HTC One S, it cannot work -- the second camera cannot be open. So is there anyone who used to do it seccessfully？ If so， please tell me which phone you worked on. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible in theory, in practice Android does not allow it at a firmware level. I'm not sure exactly what happens, but my guess is that one camera blocks some part of the API from the second one, thereby stopping two from working at once.

So for any device to do this, the manufacturer would have to change it at an OS level, and I don't think this has ever been done.

Answer (score 0):

There are currently two phones that do the trick: [Samsung Galaxy S4](http://connect.dpreview.com/post/0586582857/samsung-galaxy-s4-camera-review?page=4) and [LG Optimus G Pro](http://androidcommunity.com/lg-demos-dual-recording-feature-on-the-optimus-g-pro-20130221). Neither defines an API to 3rd parties to use this feature in their apps.