# Is it possible to open front and back cameras at the same time in Camera2

Tags: android, android-camera

I have found many questions and answers concerning this for camera api,

[open back and front cameras at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10679261/accessing-front-and-back-camera-in-android-at-the-same-time)

[open back and front cameras at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11906522/is-there-any-android-phone-allowing-to-use-both-the-rear-and-front-camera-at-the)

so i wish may be there is a way for new camera2 api.

I have been trying whole day, but couldn't find a way to make it work. 
Is there any way or new api doesn't make sense.

Thanks

Comment: Please go through [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot have more than one camera opened at the same time. At least now.