# Is it possible to use front and back Camera at same time in Android

Tags: android, android-camera

I want to use front and back Camera of device both at same time. In my app, first half of the screen will display preview of back camera and next half of the screen will display front camera preview.

I have tried this with setting two different camera previews but when I open my app, first half of the screen(which displays back camera preview) does not display the preview. And second half of the screen(which displays front facing Camera) displays back facing Camera(strange).

According to [Camera.open(int) documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open%28int%29):

> Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time
>   **for a particular hardware camera**.

This means if both camera hardware (front and back) are different and can be opened at same time.

In my application, I am using the same above api. This does not give any exception or error when I open and call `Camera.startPreview();` for both cameras at same time. But still it is not working. I can see only one camera preview at a time.

Is there anything which I am missing here to use both cameras at same time?

Comment: worked for me on a Nexus 6 running M but fails on other devices

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I got simultaneous dual camera access working on the HTC ONE M8

Video: http://youtu.be/lt8N1Lpa9Zw
Feel free to use my code from here: https://bitbucket.org/jens_grubert/androiddualcameracapture/

Comment: OK..will check it out

Comment: Does not work. fails on acquiring 2nd camera. Camera2 API may support this though.

Comment: @user3094508: Have you done framework chages? In Samsung phone, it is not possible to create two camera instances.

Comment: Seems to be device dependant, I was able to successfully open 2 cameras on a Nexus 6 but none of my other devices.

Comment: It works! If your device uses Android 6.0 (API 23) or above, don't forget to request camera permission in runtime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275906/how-to-ask-permission-for-camera-in-run-time

Comment: I had checked the bitbucket project but , but couldn't find the openCV usage

Comment: Works with Nexus 6.

Answer (score 4):

Same as a single camera... Just double.

Two SurfaceHolders, and two Camera instances.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4591023/1602230

http://developer.sprint.com/show_thread.do?forumId=528&threadid=26999&messageId=78914

[Using both cameras on android: "Fail to connect to camera service"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215230/using-both-cameras-on-android-fail-to-connect-to-camera-service)

Refered from https://stackoverflow.com/a/8411122/1602230

Comment: I have gone through above links already. But all says the same thing. Its not possible. :(

Comment: Hardwares are different. but they both belong to Camera Class, and you cannot open two camera connections at the same time. even if camera instance is opened in your app no other application can open camera instance. you have to release camera instance so other apps can use it.

Answer (score -4):

No

> Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time for a particular hardware camera.

look at this **http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#open(int)**

Comment: This is for the old android.hardware.camera API. android.hardware.camera2's <a href="https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html#openCamera(java.lang.String, android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice.StateCallback, android.os.Handler)" title="openCamera link">CameraManager.openCamera</a> doesn't state this limitation.

Comment: It clearly says one object *per hardware camera*. Nothing there implies that you cannot have one instance for the front camera and another for the rear camera.