# How I process Fail to connect to camera service and multi camera open on android?

Tags: android, android-camera

I want two camera control

first when I try only one camera mounting.
I see camera preview

```
public class AndroidCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{

    Camera camera;
    Camera camera2;
    SurfaceView surfaceView2;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder2;

     Button buttonStartCameraPreview, buttonStopCameraPreview;

    boolean previewing = false;
    LinearLayout get_more;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


       buttonStartCameraPreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startcamerapreview);
       buttonStopCameraPreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopcamerapreview);


        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);
        surfaceView2 = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview2);

        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        surfaceHolder2 = surfaceView2.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder2.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder2.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);


        buttonStartCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (!previewing) {
                    camera = Camera.open(0);
                   if (camera != null){
                        try {
                            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                            camera.startPreview();
                            previewing = true;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        buttonStopCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (camera != null && previewing) {
                    camera.stopPreview();
                    camera.release();
                    camera = null;

                    previewing = false;
                }

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

and I want two camera control

but I not find multi camera control

How can I programming?

I use surfaceview 
please advice for me

Comment: you are just handling one camera here with open(0), can´t see where your second cam should be opened. Anyway, I think this is not possible at all devices, that seems  to be hardware dependant and should not be done (that doesn´t mean it is impossible) as described in API `Your application should only have one Camera object active at a time for a particular hardware camera. ` . But try your luck, here maybe a helpful link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12382322/is-it-possible-to-use-front-and-back-camera-at-same-time-in-android

Comment: and I try camera.open(1) ?

Comment: if you want to use both cameras, then you have to use open(0) AND open(1)....but I suggested, it might not be possible....